# UnsatisfiedDependencyException during test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use psring boot 2, postgres and Jpa with hibernate.

I would like to test one of my class

```
@Component
public class ExportsFacade {

    private SamplesService sampleService;
    private SamplesRepository sampleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ExportsFacade(SamplesService sampleService, SamplesRepository sampleRepository) {
        this.sampleService = sampleService;
        this.sampleRepository=sampleRepository;
    }

    ...

}
```

I created this test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class ExportsFacadeTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExportsFacade exportsFacade;

    @Test
    public void export() throws IOException {
        exportsFacade.generateExport();
    }
}
```

I get this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'com.lcm.facade.ExportsFacadeTest':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'exportsFacade'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.lcm.facade.ExportsFacade' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: What happens if you add [@SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications) annotation to the `ExportsFacadeTest`?

Comment: work... in documentation: 43.3.12 Auto-configured Data JPA Tests

You can use the DataJpaTest annotation to test JPA applications. By default, it configures an in-memory embedded database, scans for Entity classes, and configures Spring Data JPA repositories. Regular Component beans are not loaded into the ApplicationContext.

Comment: That's right. A useful test to check whether your autowire works as expected is: @Test
    public void validateAutowireWorks() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(classUnderTest);
    }